# Asset Storeに繋がらなくなった。

Tags: unity3d

タイトル通り以下のようになりました。 
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうすれば繋がるのか教えてください。

調べたところ，「edit > project settings > player, untick ‘use direct3d 11′」のチェックを外せばいいとありましたが，どこなのかわかりません。それらしいところのチェックを外しても繋がりませんでした。
http://hidex97.hotcom-web.com/wordpress/?p=212

試した画像は以下です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Unityのバージョンは5.4.2f2です。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/53414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私の環境でも、同様の現象が発生しました。

動作環境： Unity 5.4.2f2
　　　　　　MacOS - Sierra

メニューからAssetStoreを開くと、Editor内のウインドウに結合されますが、外した状態(フロート状態)にすると、これまでと同様のAssetStoreが表示されました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！　その方法で繋がりました。 macOS Sierra 10.12.1